# prove a recurrence relationship grows unbounded

Tags: recurrence-relations, upper-lower-bounds

So I am doing this problem:

Let $p_{n+1}=\sqrt{(p_n)^2+(1/p_n)^2}$.

Prove that this sequence will grow unbounded.

I am really sure about this will grow unbounded; however I can't find a way to use the formal definition of a bounded series and use contradiction to prove this together;

I have for every $p_n$ there exist a $m$ such that $m>p_n$ and set up $m>\sqrt{(p_n)^2+(1/m)^2}$ but I think I cant proceed from here. Some suggestion will be appreciated. (I don't really prefer a derivative as I hope to do this with pre-calculus level or lower.)

Comment: Let $a_n=p_n^2$ and look for questions about $$a_{n+1} = a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}$$ and $a_n=\Omega(\sqrt{n})$, which follows by squaring both sides. In your case $p_n=\Omega(n^{1/4})$.

Comment: It's fairly obvious that the sequence is increasing. If it were bounded, then it would converge, but $\ldots$

Comment: um can we know it increases indefinitely without taking derivative?

Comment: I still hope there is a solution that  uses this formal definition: I hope that I will be able to play around it

Comment: @Guywhofailedeverything `can we know it increases` $p_{n+1}=\sqrt{p_n^2+1/p_n^2} \gt \sqrt{p_n^2} = p_n$.

Comment: oops missed this obvious point. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general fact you are using, not sure if you have seen a correct proof:  Given some real number $x_0,$ and a real function $f(x)$ with $f(x) > 0$ for $x \geq x_0,$ but $f'(x) < 0$ for $x \geq x_0.$ We do not explicitly use the derivative of $f,$ we just use the fact that it decreases.

**Theorem**: Given a sequence beginning at $x_0,$ with
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n + f(x_n) \; , $$
it follows that $x_n$ increases without bound.

**Proof**:  Assume there is an upper bound $U > x_0.$  Indeed, let us get ambitious, let $L > x_0$ be the least upper bound of the sequence elements. 
Thus there is some $x_n > L - f(L).$ If $x_n = L,$ then $x_{n+1} > L.$ If $L - f(L) < x_n < L,$ then $f(x_n) > f(L),$ so 
$$x_{n+1} = x_n + f(x_n) > L - f(L) + f(x_n) > L - f(L) + f(L) = L.$$
Either way, we have a contradiction of the existence of an upper bound.

I'm pretty sure something like this is an exercise in Rudin.  Notice that we are saying that 
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n + e^{-x_n}  $$
increases without bound. Go Figure.